# Something similar to the Sketchflow map for actual applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, organization, sketchflow

I was very excited when i first used sketchflow, and i fell in love with the little navigation thing at the bottom.

http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/9835/a31ae82fde614b3592e0ab8.png

i have a program that has to follow a certain navigation scheme, and i was wondering if it was possible to create some sort of chart like this, for organization and reference purposes easily in the VS2010 Ultimate IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The SketchFlow Map is only available for SketchFlow projects in Blend. Your app can certainly function in a similar way using the navigation framework in Silverilght or WPF, but there is no graphical representation like this.